# Does Linux md-raid store backup metadata anywhere on the disk?

Tags: linux, raid, software-raid, mdadm, md

I know that with ext2/3/4 and other filesystems, copies of the superblock are stored throughout the disk in case the primary superblock is corrupted (https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout).

With md-raid (software raid), the superblock is stored either at the beginning or end of the disk, depending on which metadata version is used (https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/RAID_superblock_formats#Sub-versions_of_the_version-1_superblock)

| Sub-Version | Superblock Position on Device |
| --- | --- |
| 0.9 | At the end of the device |
| 1.0 | At the end of the device |
| 1.1 | At the beginning of the device |
| 1.2 | 4K from the beginning of the device |

Suppose there is a disk failure and the md superblock is corrupted.  Does md-raid store a backup superblock anywhere on the disk?

(My guess would be "no", because this would require cooperation between md-raid and the filesystem.  Filesystems have come a long way since raid support was added to Linux, so it seems plausible someone might have come up with a way to make this work).

Answer (score 10):

Your guess is only partially right: MDRAID does not store a backup superblock on the *same* disk, but the superblock on the *other* disks describe the same array geometry, effectively serving as a backup in the case a disk fails.

You can examine each disk superblock via `mdadm -E /dev/your_disk`, while an array-wide description can be dumped via `mdadm -D /dev/md_array`